# Is there something simpler than `~isempty(x)` to cast a non-scalar `x` into a boolean scalar?

Tags: matlab, syntax, casting, shortcut, notation

**short version**

Is there a less cumbersome way (as is found commonly in other languages) to "booleanize" a non-scalar `x` than `~isempty(x)`?

---

**tl;dr version**

In many languages, such as Python, when variables/symbols are evaluated in a boolean context they are automatically cast to a boolean scalar.  In particular, in such a context, a list-like data structure `x` is automatically cast to false if it is empty, and to true otherwise.

This means that one can write arbitrary boolean expressions using lists as operands.  For example:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 1]
>>> list2 = [2, 2, 2]
>>> list3 = [3, 3, 3, 3]
>>> yesno = list1 and list2 and list3
>>> if yesno:
...   print True
... else:
...   print False
... 
True
```

In MATLAB this doesn't quite work.  For example

```
>> list1 = [1 1];
>> list2 = [2 2 2];
>> list3 = [3 3 3 3];
>> yesno = list1 && list2 && list3;
Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values. 
>> yesno = list1 & list2 & list3;
Error using  & 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

The best I can come up with is something like this:

```
>> yesno = ~isempty(list1) && ~isempty(list2) && ~isempty(list3);
>> if yesno
  true
else
  false
end
ans =
     1
```

Is there a less cumbersome notation than `~isempty(...)` for "booleanizing" a
  MATLAB array?

Comment: I don't get your question entirely. You have multiple arrays and you want to compare if there all non-empty?

Comment: Is it important that you are able to do boolean operations on lists of different length, or is the question more about clean notation for the operators themselves?

Comment: @xenoclast: both are important.  Basically, I'm looking for the closest notational equivalent to what one can do in Python, as shown in the tl;dr version of my question.

Comment: OK my answer isn't valid then, I deleted it and a comment on @thewaywewalk's answer.

Comment: I still don't get it. You want to compare arrays of different lenghts. That is not possible in Matlab unless you want to check if there is `any` element true or `all` elements true. Please be much clearer on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Completely agree with other answers: there is absolutely nothing wrong with `isempty`. What you call booleanizing is better known as _[Truth Value Testing‌​](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)_. In Python empty lists implicitly evaluate to `False` in a boolean condition, and I agree with you that it's less cumbersome, but on the other hand it's less immediate to understand what's really going on when things don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short: No, there isn't and ~isempty() is fine coding.
You could shorten it slightly by

```
yesno = ~isempty(l1)*~isempty(l2)*~isempty(l3)
```

cheers

Answer (score 2):

There is actually nothing wrong with `isempty`.

You could use this approach to get it a little less cumbersume:

```
list1 = [1, 1];
list2 = [2, 2, 2];
list3 = [3, 3, 3, 3];
list4 = [];

yesno = all(~cellfun(@isempty, {list1,list2,list3,list4}))
```

If you don't mind reorganizing your data, it is a really handy option:

```
lists{1} = [1, 1];
lists{2} = [2, 2, 2];
lists{3} = [3, 3, 3, 3];
lists{4} = [];

yesno = all(~cellfun(@isempty,lists))
```

The combination of [**`cellfun`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and [**`isempty`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html) is supposed to be really fast, though I'm lacking the source for this statement right now.

Comment: @xenoclast I'd say if the second approach using cell arrays from the scratch is a neat option. Should be definitely faster than comparing every array each after each.

Comment: Less cumbersome and definitely very elegant solution, especially if you organize the data in a `cell` array. Only if you have a large number of lists this might not be the best solution because `cellfun` applies the function `isempty` to all elements (if there is an empty list at the beginning of the `cell` array, I would avoid to search in other locations).